# Difference between using DSE Advanced Replication vs Manual Multi-DC Setup for Disaster Recovery?

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I want to set up up a second cluster primarily for disaster recovery. I came across [DSE Advanced Replication](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/advReplication/advRepTOC.html) but I'm unsure what's the difference in functionality between DSE Advanced Replication vs [manually setting up a Multi-DC Setup](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/initialize/initMultipleDS.html).

DSE Advanced Replication seems easier to setup and does not interfere with the replication-factor on writes (CMIIW). Can DSE Advanced Replication be used in setting up a second cluster for disaster recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced replication is usually used to setup things like, spoke-hub replication - when you copy data from smaller clusters into bigger cluster, unidirectional replication, when the connection between clusters is not permanent, etc.

In multi-DC setup, your DCs are forming the **single cluster**. In Advanced replication you're copying data between **different clusters**.